# Force Browser Mode=IE8 and document mode=IE8 Standards

Tags: internet-explorer-8, compatibility-mode

I have a internal website hosted on IIS. I added the following meta code and also add http-header that the page should in IE8 Browser mode and document mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

We tested it on Visual Studio and and it works very well.

However, after we publish the code to another IIS server, one developer reported that the page render in "IE8 Comatiblity" Browser Mode which causes some JavaScript to fail.

There are more then 4 people working on the same windows server 2003 (RDP sessions).
We use the same version of IE (same IE actually). Everyone get "IE8" Browser Mode but one person gets "IE8 Compatibility" Browser Mode.

What else can make a specific user's IE load the page in a mode other than IE8 mode?

PS.
We checked the compatibility list in the IE; it is empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We found it was caused by the checkbox in "Compatibility view settings" - "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".

It works well after uncheck the box.

PS.
 Is it true that "localhost" is excluded from intranet sites?

Comment: i suppose that localhost is ur own computer, not intranet (internal net resource). But sounds strange :) Theoretically, it should be in intranet.. Microsoft always makes strange magic :)

Answer (score 2):

its still opening in "Compat View " Mode but in its works, no differences in UI aftert adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

script

Comment: Make sure to add a doctype. `<!DOCTYPE html>` works.