# IE8 forcing document mode as IE7 standards

Tags: internet-explorer-8

For my webapplication I am using IE8 as a standard browser.Sometimes the browser is setting Document mode as IE-7 Standards.

I have already tried Servlet Headers as IE=8,IE=edge and all other settings,also my DOCTYPE is also proper.

Does anyone knows why IE is forcing such behaviour ?

Comment: Can you share the doctype and the meta tags used

Comment: check your doctype properly. if it is not correct. then it will force to quirk mode.

Comment: which server are you using(iis, apache)?

Answer (score 2):

You can force IE to use compatibility mode with [X-UA-Compatible Meta Tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm):

IE 7:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=7">
```

IE 8:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8">
```

IE 9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">
```

IE look also at the page DOCTYPE:

**Standards View**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This page is NOT Rendered in Compatibility View</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This page is NOT Compatibility View</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Compatibility View**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This page is NOT Rendered in Compatibility View</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This page is NOT Compatibility View</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Standards View**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This page is NOT Rendered in Compatibility View</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This page is NOT Compatibility View</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Compatibility View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This page is NOT Rendered in Compatibility View</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This page is NOT Compatibility View</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note, that last example should load as standards view in XHTML mode. But Internet Explorer interprets that XML declaration as requiring compatibility view.**

Comment: Here is the Meta Tag :-
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8">

and this is Doctype
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->

Comment: @Magician in the head section

Comment: yeah I have added that Meta Tag .There is no other meta tag.If I change the Document Mode manually It is working but somehow sometimes I am getting the same issue.I have checked all the things even Code also verified so as such there are no code level mistakes.

Comment: @Magician are you using XHTML?

Comment: @Magician have you seen my examples?

Comment: yes :) I already explored almost all possible solutions for the same unfortunately nothing is working for me...

Comment: This doesn't always work if the server is set differently. You need to edit the httpd.conf file possibly...

Comment: @buildakicker we don't know wich server Magician is using. Anyway good point!

Comment: @giammin good point :) However, if nothing else fixes it... then that is the fix.

Comment: Check doctype, meta tag, and also LAN pref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2597406/819417

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar issue like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9,IE=10,chrome=1" />
```

Take into account IE version should start from the lowest version.